# CSS Grid - row spanning with circular logic

Tags: css, css-grid

I know that

```
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
```

will make a cell in the first column to span the entire row. Is there an
equivalent if the cell is not in the first column?

For example, something like

```
  grid-column: 4 / -4;
```

That will span the entire row.

Comment: Wouldn't `4 / -1` do what you want?

Comment: @DavidThomas no this will simply make it at the last one ... I think we want to always cover the row but the content to be placed differently within column

Comment: I think I'm missing a large aspect of this question. @susdu: is there any chance you could [edit] to make it more clear (to me, if no one else) what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: `grid-column: 1 / -1;` is a shortcut for `grid-column-start: 1; grid-column-end: -1;`. It doesn't take a grid item that would start in first column; it makes it start at 1! You may try `grid-column: auto / -1;` or `grid-column-end: -1;` depending on what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea is to consider a sub-grid that fill the whole row inside where you adjust the position of the content:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  margin:5px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.item {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: inherit; /*should be the same as the main grid*/
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <span class="item"><span style="grid-column:1">some text</span></span>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <span class="item"><span style="grid-column:2">some text</span></span>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <span class="item"><span style="grid-column:3">some text</span></span>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <span class="item"><span style="grid-column:4">some text</span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the behavior I was looking for